# Create a new column for comments added to excel cell

Tags: r

I have a data in excel in the format as shown below. The user may add comments to the score column using 'Insert Comment' option in excel. I would like to extract the comments added to scores column and put it in the column 'Comments'. Is this possible? Can you please help?

```
Report  Component   Score   Comments
R1          C1       1
R2          C2       2
R3          C3       3
R4          C4       4
R5          C5       5
```

Here is the code I have written so far. Not sure how to proceed further. PLease help.

```
require(readxl)
read_excel("Testfile01.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to see this kind of functionality in `read_excel`, but in the mean time, you could perhaps write comments into cell content using just prior to importing the file into R.

From [ExtendOffice](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/765-excel-convert-comments-to-cells.html):

```
Function GetComments(pRng As Range) As String
'Updateby20140509
If Not pRng.Comment Is Nothing Then
    GetComments = pRng.Comment.Text
End If
End Function
```

You can then use `GetComments` function, e.g. `=GetComments(A1)`.

[image]